# Avoid extra process in unordered_map insertion

Tags: c++, memory-management, reference, unordered-map

I have an `std::unordered_map`, and I want both to increment the first value in a `std::pair`, hashed by `key`, and to create a reference to `key`. For example:

```
std::unordered_map<int, std::pair<int, int> > hash;
hash[key].first++;

auto it(hash.find(key));
int& my_ref(it->first);
```

I could, instead of using the `[]` operator, insert the data with `insert()`, but I'd allocate a pair, even if it were to be deallocated later, as `hash` may already have `key` -- not sure of it, though. Making it clearer:

```
// If "key" is already inserted, the pair(s) will be allocated
// and then deallocated, right?
auto it(hash.insert(std::make_pair(key, std::make_pair(0, 0))));
it->second.first++;

// Here I can have my reference, with extra memory operations,
// but without an extra search in `hash`
int& my_ref(it->first);
```

I'm pretty much inclined to use the first option, but I can't seem to decide which one is the best. Any better solution to this?

P.S.: an ideal solution for me would be something like an insertion that does not require an initial, possibly useless, allocation of the value.

Comment: Note that the allocation/deallocation does not take place in dynamic memory (aka "the heap") but in automatic memory (i.e. on the stack). A call to `malloc` is made once the `unordered_map` decides to actually insert the item --- **if it decides so**.

Comment: @bitmask Doesn't the expression `std::make_pair(...)` get solved before being passed as argument to `hash.insert(...)`?

Comment: Yes, but `std::pair<X,Y>` is still just a fancy way of saying `struct XYpair {X first; Y second;};` and `make_pair` returns the pair on the stack. Nobody there allocates dynamic memory. They just shuffle some `int`s around and most of that is probably going to be optimised out anyway.

Comment: @bitmask In this particular case, with an `std::pair<X, Y>`, I absolutely agree with you, they're just two integers in the stack, used as parameter. But, once I were to use an `std::vector<X>` as the hash key, and made the insertion like `std::make_pair(std::vector<int>(..., ...), ...)`, would it still be managed in the stack? A vector would necessarily go down to the heap, wouldn't it? And this `std::vector<>` idea applies both for the key and the value. Still in the first case, with the `std::pair<X, Y>`, that would be extra -- unnecessary -- processing.

Comment: Yes, `std::vector`s carry their data in dynamic memory (unless empty). Their automatic counterparts are `std::array`s, which do *not* require calls to `malloc` but have a compile-time-fixed size. Anyway, containers are nasty to hash, so if you really have them as keys to dictionaries, you really don't have to worry about an extra pointer deref.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As others have pointed out, a "allocating" a `std::pair<int,int>` is really nothing more than copying two integers (on the stack). For the `map<int,pair<int,int>>::value_type`, which is `pair<int const, pair<int, int>>` you are at three `int`s, so there is no significant overhead in using your second approach. You can slightly optimize by using `emplace` instead of `insert` i.e.:

```
// Here an `int` and a struct containing two `int`s are passed as arguments (by value)
auto it(hash.emplace(key, std::make_pair(0, 0)).first);
it->second.first++;

// You get your reference, without an extra search in `hash`
// Not sure what "extra memory operations" you worry about
int const& my_ref(it->first);
```

Your first approach, using both `hash[key]` and `hash.find(key)` is bound to be more expensive, because an element search will certainly be more expensive than an iterator dereference.

Premature copying of arguments on their way to construction of the `unordered_map<...>::value_type` is a negligible problem, when all arguments are just `int`s. But if instead you have a heavyweight `key_type` or a `pair` of heavyweight types as `mapped_type`, you can use the following variant of the above to forward everything by reference as far as possible (and use move semantics for rvalues):

```
// Here key and arguments to construct mapped_type 
// are forwarded as tuples of universal references
// There is no copying of key or value nor construction of a pair 
// unless a new map element is needed.
auto it(hash.emplace(std::piecewise_construct, 
                        std::forward_as_tuple(key), // one-element tuple
                        std::forward_as_tuple(0, 0) // args to construct mapped_type
                     ).first);
it->second.first++;

// As in all solutions, get your reference from the iterator we already have
int const& my_ref(it->first);
```

Comment: How do you know that "there is no copying unless the element is needed"? Do you have an example implementation for which this is true?

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
auto it = hash.find(key);

if (it == hash.end()) { it = hash.emplace(key, std::make_pair(0, 0)).first; }

++it->second.first;

int const & my_ref = it->first;   // must be const
```

(If it were an ordered map, you'd use `lower_bound` and hinted insertion to re­cycle the tree walk.)

Comment: I want the reference to refer to `key`, stored in `hash`, but I guess this (`int & my_ref = it == hash.end() ? hash[key].first : it->first;`) is referring to the value in the pair in `hash[key].first`.

Comment: @Rubens: Here's an [example](http://ideone.com/HEmcs0). By the time you have `it`, I would probably not even bother with the additional reference and just use `it->first`...

Comment: Thanks for your reply! The main purpose of the reference is that I'm creating objects that do only store references to common data -- instead of going on replicating information. I'm using `const &`'s to do so. I really just wanted to reduce a bit more the processing involved, as doing to unnecessary searches/allocations seemed not very neat to me. I guess that's the only way around it, though \= Thanks for your attention, once more! (:

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, what you want is an `operator[]` that returns an `iterator`, not a `mapped_type`. The current interface of `unordered_map` does not provide such feature, and `operator[]` implementation relies on private members (at least the boost implementation, I don't have access C++11 std files in my environment).

I suppose that JoergB's answer will be faster and Kerrek SB's one will have a smaller memory footprint. It's up to you to decide what is more critical for your project.